# selectizeInput in RShiny does not allow next input to be "tabbed" to when too many choices?

Tags: r, shiny, tabbing, selectinput

(When I say "tabbed", I mean keyboard's Tab button to move around.) 
It appears `selectizeInput()` does not allow me to use "Tab" key on the keyboard to highlight next input (in example below, `textInput`) afterwards. 
UPDATE: It seems to have to do with the fact that my `times` variable is length 96 - perhaps that's too long? (when I use `tail(times,5)` instead, it seems to "tab to next input" just fine.

```
times <- gsub(" ","0",sort(apply(
  expand.grid(seq(0,23),c(":00",":15",":30",":45")),1,
  function(x) paste0(as.character(x), collapse=""))))

shinyApp(
  ui = function(req) {
    fluidPage(
      selectizeInput("time", "Time:",choices=times),
      textInput("descr","Description:")
    )
  },
  server = function(input, output, session) {      }
)
```

Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Can be reproduced on Firefox 70 on macOS (High Sierra), both the problematic behavior and the desired behavior with a shorter list of choices. No idea a fix though!

Comment: I don't have the problem in chrome. In firefox it works if you do a reverse tab (shift+tab).

Comment: Good point about reproducibility! It's **not** reproducible in Opera 65 on Ubuntu 18.04. But I generally use Firefox - and the problem persists in 64-bit Firefox 67 on Ubuntu 18.04... Yes, reverse-tab "fixes" the issue even in Firefox. However, I'd rather not have to communicate to the end users the "work-around" like this. Hoping for suggestions from others.